# Comparing the Same Individuals in Different Time Periods in R

Tags: r, compare, match, inner-join

I have individual level data for selected weeks of a survey.  Each week is recorded in a separate data frame.  I have merged them vertically, but I don't know how to compare individuals who appear in two or more weeks.  Each individual has a unique identifier.  Do I need to label each variable and reference the week then do a inner join?  That would be a very lengthy process.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You could try duplicated() on unique identifier.

```
podetail <- structure(list(
    po_num = c(110, 110, 120, 120, 130),
    Item = c(
      "Toy Cat", "Toy Bear", "Screw",
      "Tools", "Toy Sneak"
    ),
    Amount = c(500, 500, 100, 200, 500)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -5L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
duplicated(podetail$po_num)

[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```